# Why are curly brackets needed when using jQuery to adjust width and height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

The following code to double an objects width and height works fine.  I just can't understand why curly brackets are needed.

```
var target = $('#target');
target.css({
    width: target.width() * 2,
    height: target.height() * 2
});
```

Comment: The curly braces are JS syntax for defining an object, which you are providing to the `css()` method. The object can be used to contain multiple properties which should be updated in a single call.

Comment: Since javascript doesn't have direct syntax support for named parameters, it uses the idiom of passing an object literal to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

The curly brackets are needed because you are passing an object literal as a parameter to the jQuery `.css` function. According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function) you can use it like this:

> **.css( properties )**
>   properties
>   Type: PlainObject
>   An object of property-value pairs to set.

So `width` and `height` are not two different parameters. They are two different properties of a single object, where the property name is the style to change and the property value the value to change it to.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) has the following to say about object literals:

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

If you for some reason want to avoid using object literals, you can do it like this:

```
target.css("width", target.width()*2);
target.css("height", target.height()*2);
```

Or this:

```
target.width(target.width()*2);
target.height(target.height()*2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Curly braces `{}` are needed to set multiple `CSS` properties. Here you are trying to set `width` and `height`.

Just **[check here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)** for more info on this and here is an official **[jquery api reference](http://api.jquery.com/css)**.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to use this

```
var target=$('#target');
target.css("width",target.width()*2);
target.css("height",target.height()*2);
```

Comment: No, OP's code is perfectly fine. He's asking what the purpose of the curly braces is.

Comment: If you want to use multiple attribute with single line of jQuery.You have to use {}.

Comment: heh... I raised a not an answer flag and it got disputed... Yours got uprooted. :)